# Span a word or text over two pages horizontally

Tags: page-breaking, text

I am looking into how I could go about to achieve spanning a text, word or symbol over two pages horizontally, without any breaks in between. Find attached screenshots of what I mean. It cannot be an image based solution since the text is generated for hundreds of cases which are unknown. It has to be a typeset solution.

[image]

[image]

Comment: typeset the pages as separate one page (wide) documents then include the pdf twice using `\includegraphics` once on each main page clipping to the appropriate side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produce nearly the same but with some overlapping text in the margins:

```
\documentclass{extarticle}
\usepackage{poster}
\begin{document}
\poster[crop=none,paperwidth=21cm,imagewidth=17.6cm,hcerter=true]{
\begin{minipage}{35cm}
\fontsize{70}{90}\selectfont
This is a short line of text. This is a very  long line of text. This is a very very very nice long line of text. 
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

> [image: mwe]

If you do not want overlapping text you can try some like this:

```
\documentclass{extarticle}
\usepackage{poster}
\begin{document}
\poster[crop=none,paperwidth=21cm,imagewidth=21cm,hcenter=true]{
\begin{minipage}{35cm}
\fontsize{70}{90}\selectfont
This is a short line of text. This is a very  long line of text. This is a very very very nice long line of text. 
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

> [image: mwe2]

But I do not recommend this, because most probably you will face with  your printer limitations, i.e., probably you cannot print completely the splitted "e" and "v" characters in this example.